# Microsoft Graph API Bad request while creating an event

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an event in my calendar on Office 365 using Graph API with the following request body,

```
{
  "subject": null,
  "body": {
    "contentType": "0",
    "content": "Event9e890101-30eb-41e1-99ac-aebd453d27a9"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": {
      "dateTime": "2018-05-19T11:17:30.2069056-04:00",
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    }
  },
  "_end": {
    "dateTime": {
      "dateTime": "2018-05-19T12:17:30.2119221-04:00",
      "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    }
  },
  "location": { "displayName": "Your office" },
  "attendees": {
    "type": "0",
    "emailAddress": { "address": "email@calendar.onmicrosoft.com" }
  }
}
```

But I get a `400` response,

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Requests must contain extension changes exclusively.",
    "innerError": { "request-id": "67884664-d5e8-4502-ad5b-94aa0e538341", "date": "2018-05-16T15:17:47" }
  }
}
```

I am not using any extensions. I tried adding an extension in the request body that didnt work too. Any pointers please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_end` isn't a valid property of an [event](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_events), it should be `end`:

```
},
"end": {
```